# getting an error while transforming the text data to feature vectors that can be used as input to the Logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6O4W.png)][[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAHJ1.png)]
please give me the solution anyone

ive tried but no result

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You did a **type error**. Here is the explaination:

This is simply due to the fact that you wrote `lowercase='True'` instead of `lowercase=True` in the definition of your `TfIdfVectorizer`.

Indeed, `'True'` written like this is a string, not a boolean, whereas `True` is a boolean.

Comment: No worries. Don't hesitate to accept my answer if you think it deserves it.